# Group Concat in MySql

Tags: mysql, group-concat

I have a sample table with some records. I show the table structure and the expected output. Please help me to do this. Now i use Group_Concat but its showing 1,1 and 2,2 and 3,3 in ids field.

```
ID  PRODUCT     QUANTITY
1   COMPUTER    100
2   MOUSE       120
3   KEYBOARD    10
4   MOUSE       150
5   KEYBOARD    300
6   COMPUTER    20
7   KEYBOARD    1
```

Eexpected Output

```
ID  PRODUCT QUANTITY    IDS
1   COMPUTER    120     1,6
2   MOUSE       270     2,4
3   KEYBOARD    311     3,5,7
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ORDER BY ID(outer) will show you the first id for a product, 

DISTINCT in group_concat compels all ids to be distinct and ORDER BY makes them in order

try this:

```
SELECT
    ID, PRODUCT, SUM(QUANTITY) QUANTITY, GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT ID ORDER BY ID) IDS
FROM
    <table>
GROUP BY PRODUCT
ORDER BY ID
;
```

Answer (score 1):

Try like this:

```
select min(id) ID, product, sum(quantity), group_concat(id) IDS
from table1
group by product
order by min(id);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `sum` for total quantity, with `group by product` and then `order by id`

**Example**:

```
select
  product, sum( quantity ) as quantity
  , group_concat( id ) as ids
from products
group by product
order by id
;
```

Comment: I got the out put with IDS 1,1 and 2,2 and 3,3,3 like this. But my result should be the above format.